# Required message given in datelist field is not working

Tags: webforms

I have created a webform and it's working fine, but the *datelist* field doesn't take the required message which given in the webform. It's displaying *required message* appended to the label with a date.

How can I add my own required message?

Comment: This is a bug. I created this issue to look into and hopefully fix it. https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2929528

Comment: Can i solve this issue by replacing Datelist.php code with your code? Do i need to do anything more ?

Comment: Fixed! Please download the latest dev release or apply the patch. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2929528

Comment: Thanks, it's working for me.But for custom form, how we can do this.For webform it's ok now.I have datelist field in custom form and validation message show as above mentioned issue.

Comment: You would have to write a patch for Drupal core or write custom code to fix the issue.

Comment: Is there any option, to prevent core datelist field validation ?

Comment: You can create an issue in the Drupal core issue queue or could copy from the webform module to fix this issue.